# How to deploy SSRS different Connection String to different environment?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, connection-string

I am using SQL Server and SSRS 2017.

When I deploy C# codes, I can use .config file to set variables differently based on the environment, for ex:

```
On DEV, the variable MyDBConString in the config file = Data Source=MyDEVSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB
On UAT, the variable MyDBConString in the config file= Data Source=MyUATSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB
```

How can I do this with SSRS, because there is no .config file.

When it deploys the .rds (Data Source) file, it sets it to the connection string that I have in Visual Studio (for ex: Data Source=MyDEVSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB).

So, when I go the report itself, the Data Source Connection string is set to Data Source=MyDEVSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB

How can I deploy the SSRS so that the .rds will be different by environment ?

Thank you

Comment: Don't deploy your shared data source... keep that as site unique.

Comment: Alternatively... deploy the same connection string to all environments and have an application-specific alias, e.g.: SsisDataSource, in each environment's SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Native Client Configuration > Aliases.

Comment: As Dale K suggested. It better to use shared datasources. If these have the same name on both your dev and production servers then when you deploy the report it will use the datasource with that name. `By default` datasources are NOT overwritten when you deploy reports so once the shared data sources are setup in each environment there is nothing more to do.

Answer (score 0):

An expression can be used in the Data Source to construct the connection sting based on a parameter.

Create a text parameter for the Environment.

Create a new dataset. Click on the Expression button [Fx] to open the expression builder.

Create a SWITCH statement that creates the connection string for each possibility of the parameter selected.

For this example, we had the username and password the same for each environment but that can be added to the individual strings for the environment.

[image]

Comment: As others have mentioned the proper way to do this is to have separate DEV and PROD servers with different connection strings that point to the same environment.